# Cassandra 1.2 - Large compactions staying at 100%

Tags: cassandra

I have a 8 node setup, each with equal ranges of tokens, and the ring is loaded with about ~800 GB distributed evenly-ish across the ring.  We are using the LeveledCompactionStrategy with 160MB sstable sizes.

I have noticed large compactions (30 GB in size) occurring, which appear to get stuck for a period of time at 100%.  During this period, other tasks may build up and we develop a backlog of them, that need to clear out.

My question is, what is happening when nodetool compactionstats reports the progress is 100% and the task isn't being cleared out?  Does this have to do with the flushing of sstables to disk?

tpstats report that we have a high ratio of operations from the FlushWriter pool being in the All time blocked category.  No other pool has blocked or significant pending operations.  For example:

FlushWriter                       0         0           7617         0              1540